# Array in parameter BleuJ

Tags: java, arrays

I cant seem to find what I have to put in to get this working.
The beginning of my code in BleuJ looks like this.

```
public Aandeel(String code, String naam, double dividend, double[] tab)
{
    this.code = code;
    this.naam = naam;
    setDividend(dividend);
    waarden = new double[12];
    setWaarden(tab);
}
```

So I have no clue how I can fill in a good parameter for tab.
I trief everything but I keep having these errors.
( Im talking about the last parameter)

[image]

Comment: Some code appears to be missing, and it's not possible to answer the question without additional information. Can you post the rest of the code from the `Aandeel` class?

Comment: [IMG]http://i60.tinypic.com/avn8gj.png[/IMG]

Comment: Hi, thanks already for looking into it. I posted a pic with the rest of the code

Comment: Also, it's faster to use the `ctrl+c` shortcut instead of posting screenshots of the code.

Comment: well, not if the code is longer then 600 characters. Wouldnt post it inhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not super familiar with BlueJ but it looks like your array isn't being created right. 3.43[12] won't create a new array, you should try tab[0] = 3.43. You'll have to define the size somewhere above.

Another option would be to define it like new double[]{3.43}. Whatever suits your purposes better.
I'd suggest taking a look at this question: [How do I declare and initialize an array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/declare-array-in-java)

Your array is out of bounds error is caused by i < waarden.length. You should be checking for i < tab.length. Something I would do is define waarden as new doulbe[tab.length]

so your entire class would look like:

```
public Aandeel(String code, String naam, double dividend, double[] tab)
{
    this.code = code;
    this.naam = naam;
    setDividend(dividend);
    waarden = new double[tab.length];
    setWaarden(tab);
}

public void setWaarden( double[] tab)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<tab.length; i++)
    {
         waarden[i] = tab[i]
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried the new double[]{3.43} thing. But then I get an outofbounds error.

Comment: Try passing with only {3.43}, as suggested above.

Comment: Did it. Keeps getting an arrayOutOfBoundsExeption problem

Comment: Seems to work!! thanks alot! I keep learning ^^

Answer (score 0):

In double[] tab, you should pass values in the following format:-

```
{1.0,2.0,5.8,2.4,4.23,5.2}
```

which is the error , `array required but double found`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It seems to does it now. But I keep getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExeption error?

Comment: That is a different problem ... and most likely due to some other part of your code that you haven't shown us.  But the message means that you have tried to index part of an array that does not exist.